# Python multi-thread communication efficiency

Tags: python, multithreading, performance, queue, python-multithreading

I'm new to python multitasking. I'm doing it in old-fashioned way:

I'm inheriting from threading.Thread and using queue.Queue queues to send messages to/from the main thread.

This is my base threaded class:

```
class WorkerGenerico(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, task_id, input_q=None, output_q=None, keep_alive=300):
        super(WorkerGenerico, self).__init__()
        self._task_id = task_id
        if input_q is None:
            self._input_q = queue.Queue()
        else:
            if isinstance(input_q, queue.Queue):
                self._input_q = input_q
            else:
                raise TypeError("input_q debe ser del tipo queue.Queue")
        if output_q is None:
            self._output_q = queue.Queue()
        else:
            if isinstance(output_q, queue.Queue):
                self._output_q = output_q
            else:
                raise TypeError("input_q debe ser del tipo queue.Queue")
        if not isinstance(keep_alive, int):
            raise TypeError("El valor de keep_alive debe der un int.")
        self._keep_alive = keep_alive
        self.stoprequest = threading.Event()

    # def run(self):
    #    Implement a loop in subclases which checks if self.has_orden_parada() is true in order to stop.

    def join(self, timeout=None):
        self.stoprequest.set()
        super(WorkerGenerico, self).join(timeout)

    def gracefull_stop(self):
        self.stoprequest.set()

    def has_orden_parada(self):
        return self.stoprequest.is_set()

    def put(self,texto, block=True, timeout=None):
        return self._input_q.put(texto, block=block, timeout=timeout)

    def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
        return self._output_q.get(block=block, timeout=timeout)
```

My question is how expensive it is to call WorkerGenerico.get() from the outside, as oposed to storing que queue in the main thread and using Queue.get(). **Both methods look similar in performance with small non-frequent control messages**, however, I guess that very frequent calls would make method B worth the usage.:

I guess mode A is more resource-consuming (it has to somehow call the method from an outer thread and pass the queue definition back, I guess that the loss depends on Python implementation), however, final code is more readable and intuitive.

**If I had to tell from experience with other languages, I'd say method B is much better, an I right?**

Method A:

```
def main()
    worker = WorkerGenerico(task_id=1)
    worker.start()
    print(worker.get())
```

Method B:

```
def main()
    input_q = Queue()
    output_q = Queue()
    worker = WorkerGenerico(task_id=1, input_q=input_q, output_q=output_q)
    worker.start()
    print(output_q.get())
```

BTW: For completeness, I'd like to share the way I'm doing it now. Its a mixture of both methods which offers a nice envelope to threads:

```
class EnvoltorioWorker:
    def __init__(self, task_id, input_q=None, output_q=None, keep_alive=300):
        if input_q is None:
            self._input_q = queue.Queue()
        else:
            if isinstance(input_q, queue.Queue):
                self._input_q = input_q
            else:
                raise TypeError("input_q debe ser del tipo queue.Queue")
        if output_q is None:
            self._output_q = queue.Queue()
        else:
            if isinstance(output_q, queue.Queue):
                self._output_q = output_q
            else:
                raise TypeError("input_q debe ser del tipo queue.Queue")
        self.worker = WorkerGenerico(task_id, input_q, output_q, keep_alive)

    def put(self, elem, block=True, timeout=None):
        return self._input_q.put(elem, block=block, timeout=timeout)

    def get(self, block=True, timeout=None):
        return self._output_q.get(block=block, timeout=timeout)
```

I use EnvoltorioWorker.worker.* to call joins or other outher control methods and EnvoltorioWorker.get / EnvoltorioWorker.put to communicate with the inner class properly, just like this:

```
def main()
    worker_container = EnvoltorioWorker(task_id=1)
    worker_container.worker.start()
    print(worker_container.get())
```

Normally I also make interfaces for start(), join() and nonwait_stop() in EnvoltorioWorker if no other access to worker is needed.

It may look dummy, and there are probably better ways to achieve this, so:

**Which method (A or B) is a better practise? Is inheriting from Thread the proper way to handle threads in Python?.** I'm using dispycos for distributed environments and similar envelopes to communicate with my threads

EDIT: Just noticed I forgot to translate comments and some strings in classes, but they're simple enough so I think it is readable. I'll edit it when I've time.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queue is not really *stored* in the thread. Assuming  CPython here, all objects are stored on the heap and threads only have a private stack. Objects on the heap are shared across all threads in the same process.

> Memory management in Python involves a private heap containing all Python objects and data structures. The management of this private heap is ensured internally by the Python memory manager. The Python memory manager has different components which deal with various dynamic storage management aspects, like sharing, segmentation, preallocation or caching. [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/c-api/memory.html)

From this follows that it's not a question *where* your object (your queue) is located, because it's always on the heap. Variables (names) in Python are just *references* to these objects.

The things here, which affect your runtime are how many call frames you add to your stacks by nesting function / method calls and how ~many bytecode instructions you need. So what impact on timings does this have?

---

**Benchmark**

Consider the following dummy setup for a queue and a worker. The dummy-worker is not threaded here for simplicity because threading it doesn't affect timings in a scenario where we pretend to just drain a pre-filled queue.

```
class Queue:
    def get(self):
        return 1

class Worker:
    def __init__(self, queue):
        self.queue = queue
        self.quick_get = self.queue.get # a reference to a method as instance attribute

    def get(self):
        return self.queue.get()

    def quick_get_method(self):
        return self.quick_get()
```

How you can see, `Worker` has two versions of get-methods, `get` in a way how *you* define it and `quick_get_method`, which is one bytecode instruction shorter how we'll see later. The worker instance not only holds a reference to the `queue` instance, but also directly to `queue.get` via `self.quick_get`, which is where we spare one instruction.

Now the timings for benchmarking all possibilities to `.get()` from the fake-queue within an IPython session:

```
q = Queue()
w = Worker(q)

%timeit q.get()
285 ns ± 1.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit w.get()
609 ns ± 2.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit w.quick_get()
286 ns ± 0.756 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
%timeit w.quick_get_method()
555 ns ± 0.855 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Note that there is no difference in timings between `q.get()` and `w.quick_get()`.
Also note the improved timing of `w.quick_get_method()` compared to the traditional `w.get()`. Using a `Worker-method` to call `get()` on the queue still nearly doubles the timings compared to `q.get()` and `w.quick_get()`. Why is that?

It's possible to get a human readable version of the Python bytecode instructions the interpreter is working on, by using the `dis` module.

```
import dis

dis.dis(q.get)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis(w.get)
  8           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              2 LOAD_ATTR                0 (queue)
              4 LOAD_METHOD              1 (get)
              6 CALL_METHOD              0
              8 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis(w.quick_get)
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (1)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

dis.dis(w.quick_get_method)
 11           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              2 LOAD_METHOD              0 (quick_get)
              4 CALL_METHOD              0
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Keep in mind our dummy `Queue.get` here is just returning 1. You see that `q.get` is just the same as `w.quick_get`, what is also reflected in the timings we saw before. Note that `w.quick_get_method` directly loads `quick_get`, which is just another name / variable for the object `queue.get` is referencing.

You can also get the depth of the stack printed with the help of the `dis` module:

```
def print_stack_depth(f):
    print(*[s for s in dis.code_info(f).split('\n') if
            s.startswith('Stack size:')]
    )

print_stack_depth(q.get)
Stack size:        1 
print_stack_depth(w.get)
Stack size:        2
print_stack_depth(w.quick_get)
Stack size:        1
print_stack_depth(w.quick_get_method)
Stack size:        2
```

Bytecode and timing differences between the different approaches imply (less surprising), that adding another frame (by adding another method) accounts for the biggest performance hit.

---

**Review**

The analysis above is not an implicit plea for not using extra Worker-methods to call methods on referenced objects (queue.get). For readability, logging and easier debugging doing this is just the right thing to do. Optimizations like `Worker.quick_get_method` you will, for example, also find in Stdlib's `multiprocessing.pool.Pool`, which also uses queues internally.

To put the timings from the benchmark into perspective, a few hundred nanoseconds is not much (for Python). In Python 3 the default maximum time interval a thread can hold the [GIL](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock) and hence, execute bytecode at a stretch, is 5 milliseconds. That's 5*1000*1000 nanoseconds.

A few hundred nanoseconds is also small compared to the overhead multi-threading introduces anyway. I found, for example, that adding a 20 μs sleep after a `queue.put(integer)` in one thread and just reading from the queue in another thread, led to an additional overhead of about 64.0 μs **per iteration on average** (the 20 μs sleep *not* included) over a range of 100k (Python 3.7.1, Ubuntu 18.04).

---

**Design**

Regarding your question about design preference, I would definitely pick Method A here over Method B. Even more in case your queues are not used across multiple threads anyway. IMO your mixed creation in the last snippet is unnecessarily complicating things / understanding in a case where you just use **one** `WorkerGenerico` instance internally (not a pool of worker-threads). Contrary to Method A, the "threadiness" of your worker here is also buried deep inside another class.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth answer. I use in average, 500 WorkersGenericos distributed across 25 computers, and they've different worker functions, thats why i enveloped'em with such that interface, in order for my pool class to be able to handle them easily. They're also used with different frameworks (some tasks that are only local are executed as standard python threads, while heavy loads are in dispycos tasks, some of which are started at the same time than the task and others are started on startup (heavy init methods) and run for hours receiving short-time tasks over network.

Comment: And yeah, I know that with such project size it would definetly not be Python, but I had to set-up a one-year project in 2 months, doing this in C++ woul've been impossible in time...

Comment: @DGoiko I see, quite complex. But why not just the Pool class for handling queues and the pure worker class? You may take a look at the source for `multiprocessing.pool.Pool` for ideas. It's written in Python. You will also find `ThreadPool` there, which inherits from `Pool`.

Comment: @DGoiko Certainly won't blame you for using Python :-) FYI, e.g. facebook also uses Python with multiprocessing/-threading, so I guess project size is not a limitation.

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at it. Right now, when I've to initialize a node's computation I send the init data (big loads expected on production) once to the node, which calculates the special data structure it needs from the data and distributes it amongs its own threads. However, some system events trigger the renewal of the init data and recalculation, which is handled in the same way than init. It looked the most natural to me to spawn the needed processes (whith option to expand) and then feed'em with compuitations the same way than init, and give results back via the same pipe

Comment: but I see your point, I could initialize the node master thread and then use python's native Pool to generate as many processes as I can locally on demand, using globals to present the data. I'm not sure, though, if the class I'm using to store data and operate with it is thread safe. It should, though. I'd still have to handle node load in the master to calculate which node to send the loads to (at this point i'm sending it to the one with most threads in waiting state, as every task consumes more or less the same CPU/MEM amount, the only thing that varies is the duration of the task)

Comment: @DGoiko I've you're operating on a cluster you probably should take a look at [dask](http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/why.html). I should also mention `multiprocessing.Manager` for sharing data in a cluster.  Regarding thread-safety of your data, any operation spanning multiple Python-bytecode instructions (check out `dis` module to see bytecode) needs to be made atomic (thread-safe) by using a lock if multiple threads operate on that same data. For example already `x += 1`  is not thread-safe without a lock around, because it needs multiple bytecode instructions.

Comment: YEah, I know. The classes I use are, theoretically, read-only, however, I'm not use if they use any internal mutable index, and if they provide methods to request index in a per-thread basis (i.e., local to search function) or not. For instance, one of my clases is an ahocorasick search algorithm, which uses trie structures. By definition, it needs an internal index to perform searches, however, if that index is implemented as a class attribute it would make it thread unsafe, while if its created locally when a search is performed, then there should be no problems.

Comment: btw, is there any python class that can properly handle communication via TCP between computers? Ideally, I'd like to have one concurrent listening TCP port in a cluster which recieves communication from several nodes, and those nodes should have their own receiving ports. Some class that can guarantee me a "true" when delivered or "false" if not, with retries timeouts and ability to choose between blocking and non-blocking. Something like queue.Queue but omn network. With dispycos it is task.deliver(), but dispycos is not very reliable, according to my tests. I mean a RELIABLE class.

Comment: @DGoiko Check out the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) for `multiprocessing.Manager` "Using a remote manager" and also read "Listeners and Clients"  there, think this will serve your purpose.

Comment: Thanks! I'm revieewing it, and I think I could inherit from Process instead of threading.Thread in order to adapt my ode quickly, however, it looks like a single node (computer) framework. Dispy looked OK on single computer test, however, when ran on Google Cloud I couldn't make it reliable. I'm still needing a framework like Pyro (https://pythonhosted.org/Pyro4/) or something like that, or stick to my own implemented node communication, am I right?

Comment: @DGoiko A ready disributed computing framework or implementing your own is certainly needed for your cluster,  unfortunately I cannot advice you which framework to pick because I have no experience with them yet.  I would generally try to keep things as simple as possible and prefer using established frameworks over trying to build my own.